# How to manually control a shake activated lamp using raspberry pi?

Tags: hardware, sensor

I got this cool potion lamp for Christmas though it’s only shake activated (more like you have to tap on it really hard) and I was wondering if there was any possible way I could connect my raspberry pi to it and be able to control it with the home bridge.

[image]

[image: This is the inside electronics. I think the cylinder on the top of this pic is the « shake » sensor]
I think the cylinder on top is the “shake” sensor but I might be wrong
Now I am a bit of a beginner so I don’t know how achievable this is. I thought maybe there’s something I can use to vibrate and activate the light directly or there’s something I can do to actually connect the two but I really have no idea how to do it. Maybe it’s just not possible but yeah I might as well try :)

Comment: Yes， I am pretty sure that the metal cylinder is the shake or vibration sensor.  Let me search later for the datasheet.

Comment: I found some notes with a long list of references on vibration/shake sensors you might find useful: https://penzu.com/p/f951e273

Comment: Your sensor should be SW420D/SW520D: AliExpress Shake Sensor Catalog::
https://www.aliexpress.com/popular/shaking-sensor.html

Comment: I highly recommend to watch Big Clive's YouTube Videos: (1) Big Clive Tearing Down 220VAC LED Lamp 1/2:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=77158&p=1344067&hilit=big+clive+tlfong01#p1344067

(2) Big Clive Tearing Down 220VAC LED Lamp 2/2:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a-exD1-6gsY&feature=youtu.be. (3) Big Clive YouTube Videos Full List:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLilYftGX4DBRB_4L7Wx4Jiy88KTFIECDv

Comment: You can find the following SW-18020 reference in my long list above: https://e-radionica.com/productdata/SW-18020.pdf

Comment: Brainstorming ideas: There are many ways for Rpi to control the shake activated lamp: (1) solder and extend two connecting wires to the two terminals of the shake sensor, to the COM and NO terminal of a 5V relay, and let Rpi control the relay. This way, you have both shake and rpi-relay control.

Comment: You should ask this question on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions or https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: @tlfong01 please convert your comments to an answer, its as close to a good answer to the question!

Comment: @Vincent P, Thank you for your good suggestion.  So I have given the answer. Cheers.

Comment: It seems a bit of a roundabout thing to do. Ultimately you want to use your pi to ... turn on a led for a while. There's *much* easier ways to accomplish that than fooling this circuit into thinking the shake-sensor has been activated. If you're mostly in it for the end-result, then just putting a RGB-led on the pi and putting it in the bottle would work.

Answer (score 3):

---

> Yes, you can use Rpi to control a 5V relay with its switch
>   contacts/terminals (COM = Common, and NO = Normally Open), connected
>   in parallel to the two terminals of the shake switch.

---

[image: shake switch]

***References***

(1) [Raspberry Pi Appliance Monitor (Using 801s vibration sensor)](https://github.com/Shmoopty/rpi-appliance-monitor#notification-settings)

(2) [AliExpress Vibration Sensor Module 801S Vibration Analog Output Sensitivity LM393 - US$2.1](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32808658968.html)

(3) [801S Vibration Sensor Module (SE040) User Manual - IduIno](https://produktinfo.conrad.com/datenblaetter/1400000-1499999/001485302-da-01-en-IDUINO_SE040_VIBRATIONS_SENSOR_MODUL.pdf)

(4) [Shock Sensor S801 Spec - electroninvest](http://www.electronicaestudio.com/docs/SHT-801S.pdf)

(5) [Using a push button with Raspberry Pi GPIO (event based) Published by Soren 2018feb08](https://raspberrypihq.com/use-a-push-button-with-raspberry-pi-gpio/)

(6) [How to Interface a Push Button with Raspberry Pi? - Ravi 2018feb](https://www.electronicshub.org/raspberry-pi-push-button-interface/)

(7) [Two Ways to Add a Button to Your Raspberry Pi Project (GPIO.Zero, Thonny Python, Beginner's YouTube tutorial)](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/add-button-raspberry-pi-project/)

(8) Rpi: The Unofficial Tutorial - Christian Cawley 207jan28
[enter link description here](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/great-things-small-package-your-unofficial-raspberry-pi-manual/)

(9) [BeeLee/Gaoxin Vibrating Detection Sensor sw-18015/20p datasheet](https://e-radionica.com/productdata/SW-18020.pdf)

(10) [XSP1TM High Output LED Street/Area Luminaire - Single Module](https://adlt.com.sg/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/ADLT-Cree-XSP-Version-D-Single-Module-Spec-Sheet.pdf)

(11) [Cree XSP Series LED STREET LIGHT](https://adlt.com.au/portfolio/cree-xsp-series-led-street-light/)

---