# How to get measured(analog/digital) output from 801s vibration sensor?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, sensor, python-3, analog-to-digital

I have Rpi3B+, 801s vibration sensor and a ADC. I need the analog output to plot a graph for analysis. Basically I need to observe how vibration is affecting the other properties of the machine. However, ADC gives me only two values 28 and 253 (I guess representing High and Low).

I need an analog or digital value like voltage change or frequency change and not just 0 and 1. Is it possible? or Do I need to try another sensor?

Comment: This might help: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/107191/how-to-manually-control-a-shake-activated-lamp-using-raspberry-pi/107237#107237

Comment: the 801s sensor is a switch that opens and closes ... it has only two states

Answer (score 2):

801 is a digital sensor, so you will not be able to get a analog output from it.

Quote: *Outputs a logic HIGH when module senses a vibration*

Ref.: https://protosupplies.com/product/801s-vibration-sensor-module/